# Define periods/episodes of exposition with overlaping and concatenated intervals of time

Tags: r, time, data.table, intervals

I'm trying to identify periods/episodes of exposition to a drug with prescriptions. If those prescriptions are separated for 30 days it's considered a new period/episode of exposition. Prescriptions can overlap during certain time or be consecutive. If the sum of separated days of two consecutive prescripction is greater than 30 days it's not considered a new episode.

I have data like this:

```
id = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,6), rep(3,5))
start = as.Date(c("2017-05-10", "2017-07-28", "2017-11-23", "2017-01-27", "2017-10-02", "2018-05-14", "2018-05-25", "2018-11-26", "2018-12-28", "2016-01-01", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-20", "2016-04-25", "2016-06-29"))
end = as.Date(c("2017-07-27", "2018-01-28", "2018-03-03", "2017-04-27", "2018-05-13", "2018-11-14", "2018-11-25", "2018-12-27", "2019-06-28", "2016-02-15", "2016-03-05", "2016-03-24", "2016-04-29", "2016-11-01"))

DT = data.table(id, start, end)

DT
    id      start        end
 1:  1 2017-05-10 2017-07-27
 2:  1 2017-07-28 2018-01-28
 3:  1 2017-11-23 2018-03-03
 4:  2 2017-01-27 2017-04-27
 5:  2 2017-10-02 2018-05-13
 6:  2 2018-05-14 2018-11-14
 7:  2 2018-05-25 2018-11-25
 8:  2 2018-11-26 2018-12-27
 9:  2 2018-12-28 2019-06-28
10:  3 2016-01-01 2016-02-15
11:  3 2016-03-02 2016-03-05
12:  3 2016-03-20 2016-03-24
13:  3 2016-04-25 2016-04-29
14:  3 2016-06-29 2016-11-01
```

I calculated the difference of start and last end observation (last_diffdays)

```
DT[, last_diffdays := start-shift(end, n=1L), by = .(id)][is.na(last_diffdays), last_diffdays := 0][]

    id      start        end last_diffdays
 1:  1 2017-05-10 2017-07-27        0 days
 2:  1 2017-07-28 2018-01-28        1 days
 3:  1 2017-11-23 2018-03-03      -66 days
 4:  2 2017-01-27 2017-04-27        0 days
 5:  2 2017-10-02 2018-05-13      158 days
 6:  2 2018-05-14 2018-11-14        1 days
 7:  2 2018-05-25 2018-11-25     -173 days
 8:  2 2018-11-26 2018-12-27        1 days
 9:  2 2018-12-28 2019-06-28        1 days
10:  3 2016-01-01 2016-02-15        0 days
11:  3 2016-03-02 2016-03-05       16 days
12:  3 2016-03-20 2016-03-24       15 days
13:  3 2016-04-25 2016-04-29       32 days
14:  3 2016-06-29 2016-11-01       61 days
```

This shows when an overlap happens (negative values) or not (positive values). I think an ifelse/fcase statement here would be a bad idea and I'm not comfortable doing it.

I think a good **output** for this job would be something like:

```
    id      start        end last_diffdays noexp_days period
 1:  1 2017-05-10 2017-07-27        0 days          0      1
 2:  1 2017-07-28 2018-01-28        1 days          1      1
 3:  1 2017-11-23 2018-03-03      -66 days          0      1
 4:  2 2017-01-27 2017-04-27        0 days          0      1
 5:  2 2017-10-02 2018-05-13      158 days        158      2
 6:  2 2018-05-14 2018-11-14        1 days          1      2
 7:  2 2018-05-25 2018-11-25     -173 days          0      2
 8:  2 2018-11-26 2018-12-27        1 days          1      2
 9:  2 2018-12-28 2019-06-28        1 days          1      2
10:  3 2016-01-01 2016-02-15        0 days          0      1
11:  3 2016-03-02 2016-03-05       16 days         16      1
12:  3 2016-03-20 2016-03-24       15 days         15      1
13:  3 2016-04-25 2016-04-29       32 days         32      2
14:  3 2016-06-29 2016-11-01       61 days         61      3
```

I manually calculated the days without exposition (noexp_days) of the before prescription.

I dunno If I'm the right path but I think I need to calculate noexp_days variable and then make a `cumsum((noexp_days)>30)+1`.

If there is a much better solution I don't see or any other possibility I haven't considered I will appreciate to read about them.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
library(data.table)

DT[, noexp_days := pmax(as.integer(last_diffdays), 0)]
DT[, period := cumsum(noexp_days > 30) + 1, id]
DT
#    id      start        end last_diffdays noexp_days period
# 1:  1 2017-05-10 2017-07-27        0 days          0      1
# 2:  1 2017-07-28 2018-01-28        1 days          1      1
# 3:  1 2017-11-23 2018-03-03      -66 days          0      1
# 4:  2 2017-01-27 2017-04-27        0 days          0      1
# 5:  2 2017-10-02 2018-05-13      158 days        158      2
# 6:  2 2018-05-14 2018-11-14        1 days          1      2
# 7:  2 2018-05-25 2018-11-25     -173 days          0      2
# 8:  2 2018-11-26 2018-12-27        1 days          1      2
# 9:  2 2018-12-28 2019-06-28        1 days          1      2
#10:  3 2016-01-01 2016-02-15        0 days          0      1
#11:  3 2016-03-02 2016-03-05       16 days         16      1
#12:  3 2016-03-20 2016-03-24       15 days         15      1
#13:  3 2016-04-25 2016-04-29       32 days         32      2
#14:  3 2016-06-29 2016-11-01       61 days         61      3
```